# Python2: Print boolean results of a function in a list format

Tags: python, list, return, boolean

```
def foodList(order, food):
    for i in order:
        if i in food:
            i= True
        else:
            i= False
```

I have a list called "order" and a list called "food" and I am trying to check each element in order to see if it exists in food. If it does, I want to return true and if it doesn't, I want to return false. I am trying to print the results of each element in a list.

For example, lets say

```
order= ["water", "wine", "sandwich", "pasta"]
```

and

```
food=["sandwich", "pasta"]
```

since sandwich and pasta is also found in order, my print statement should say

```
[False, False, True, True]
```

Comment: `[x in food for x in order]` should do it

Comment: You need to build a *new* list containing the booleans, or print them directly after finding them. As it stands now, you overwrite the result for previous items again and again.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative by fixing your method:

```
def foodList(order, food):
  res = []
  for i in order:
    if i in food: res.append(True)
    else: res.append(False)
  return res

print(foodList(order, food)) #=> [False, False, True, True]
```